# How to reset BQ Ubuntu phone when GUI is inaccessible?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm starting to mess around with the bq phone. Installing packages with apt and stuff like that. Is there a way to reset the phone when I mess things completely?

I'm looking for a way to do it when I break things so badly that I can't access the "reset" functionality in the GUI anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Warning: This will *ERASE* all your data

---

1. Switch off the phone
2. Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Power button</kbd> simultaneously for around 10 seconds.
3. Release the <kbd>Power button</kbd> when the red LED lights.
4. Afterwards press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button to enter Recovery Mode.
5. Press <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>, choose `wipe data/factory reset` and then push the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button.
6. Select `Yes--delete all user data`. Use <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> to scroll and <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> to select.
7. When Recovery Mode menu appears again select `reboot system now` to restart the phone.

If all goes well, you will have the phone as when you bought it. **Without data nor settings**

---

Thanks to [John McAleely](https://askubuntu.com/users/148116/john-mcaleely) by its contributions to this answer.

Comment: Thanks. Where is the factory reset image located on the phone? So I know what I should never ever touch...

Comment: I don't know where is located the recovery image, however you can make another question with this and anybody can answer you.

Comment: You will not see an 'android image' when you use the Ubuntu Edition. The red led turns on as the reboot occurs

Comment: @JohnMcAleely what displays? A Ubuntu logo? A black screen? Please, if do you have a Ubuntu phone or you seen one's recovery mode, please, feel free of edit my question. I don't have one.

Comment: I've made an edit that now awaits peer reviewing.

Comment: I've quoted you in the answer