# Where is the factory-reset image located on the bq Ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

The factory-reset option in system settings on the bq ubuntu phone reverts the phone back to factory settings. Where, on the phone, is the image located used by factory-reset to reset the phone?

Comment: There isn't a factory reset image as such on the device. We support re-installing the OS in various ways, but the image needs to be downloaded then installed. It's not lurking on the device already.

Comment: @popey, Then how does the "factory-reset" function on the device and the function from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/602843/172367) work?

Comment: I think that just deletes user data. It doesn't wind the clock back to the original factory image.

Comment: @popey, can you point me to documentation about re-installing the OS?

Comment: This question is answered at http://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As popey said:

> *[The factory-reset option] just deletes user data. It doesn't wind the clock back to the original factory image, so there isn't a factory image present on the device.*