# How do I factory reset a BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition, from the handset

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've been experimenting with the software on my handset, and I've got to a state where I need to recover with a factory reset.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602035/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-device-flash-with-the-bq-aquaris-e4-5) covers how do do that with `ubuntu-device-flash`. How do I do it from the handset itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset BQ Ubuntu phone when GUI is inaccessible?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/602834/how-to-reset-bq-ubuntu-phone-when-gui-is-inaccessible)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The factory reset procedure is several steps:

1. With the handset powered on in any state, hold down <kbd>VolUp</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>. After holding them for around 10 seconds, the handset starts to reboot, and the screen blanks. At this point, release the <kbd>Power</kbd> button.
2. A menu will be displayed with three options. Release the <kbd>Volup</kbd> key.

Boot menu:

```
[Recovery    Mode]
[Fastboot    Mode]
[Normal      Boot]
```

3. Use the <kbd>VolUp</kbd> Key to select Recovery, and use <kbd>VolDown</kbd> to boot to that mode.
4. When the Ubuntu Logo appears, you are in recovery, and you can press <kbd>VolUp</kbd> to reveal the recovery menu. Use the on-screen prompts to select the wipe data/factory reset option.

Comment: Notice that this won't reset the system partition, so if you've made that writable in the past, you may still be in a strange state after this. In that case, `ubuntu-device-flash` is your best option.

Comment: In my case, I never saw the red LED

Comment: Hmm, I just tried again, and also don't see the red led. I wonder if it changed recently.

Comment: It works on my device...