# How should I address the message "This phone needs restoring from a PC or service center." on a BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, aquaris

I engaged a standard Ubuntu system update as prompted by settings on my BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition. I am now presented with the following display, which features themessage "This phone needs restoring from a PC or service center.":

[image]

I have accessed `Android system recovery <3e> ALPS.KK1.MP1.V2.10` following [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/609944/204323) directions. I am presented now with the following options:

- reboot system now
- wipe data/factory reset
- wipe cache partition

What are my options if I do not want to nuke my personal data on the device?