# Factory Reset on Meizu MX4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

It lost the PIN. So, now I'm logged out of the phone.
Is there any chance to do a factory reset?

Comment: try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/609944/47291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factory reset *of the phone* will not reset your PIN-code as that is the code to your *SIM card*.  You need to enter the PUK-code or get a new SIM card from your phone provider.

To do a factory reset, [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645294/meizu-mx4-ubuntu-erased-or-changed-access-code)…

Comment: I want to add: I didn´t forget the password. I set it in the initial config, just 4 numbers, and typed it different times succesfully. Then i got no access anymore. The only thing that occured to me was a large heat generation. There are two numbers to fill in: the PIN of my sim (that works well) after that the unlocking of the lock screen/ user access.

Comment: Thanks                                                                                          http://askubuntu.com/questions/645294/meizu-mx4-ubuntu-erased-or-changed-access-code