# Meizu MX4 Ubuntu erased or changed access code

Tags: login, ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

One step in the initial configuration of Ubuntu Touch on my Meizu MX4 was to set a user password or pin code. I decided for the pin: just 4 numbers - very easy for me to remember.

While I used my phone for the first time it was very warm and then I wanted to unlock the screen again and now it doesn´t accept the pin any more.

I was trying to do a factory reset but I just could choose it. Since then it's been stuck. The normal boot mode works well and my SIM´s pin is accepted.

But now I´m logged out of the phone itself!

*How can I solve this problem?*

Answer (score 3):

According to the Manual of the phone on page 18 you have to press the <kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> buttons simultaneously,

[image: Meizu MX4 buttons]

then go to <kbd>Settings</kbd>→<kbd>User data</kbd>→<kbd>Factory reset</kbd> and check the <kbd>Clear Data Simultaneously</kbd> check box during the eventual firmware update.

And that should clear all settings.  If that doesn't solve your problem, press the <kbd>Power</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> buttons simultaneously for 10 seconds and that should then completely reset your phone.

If that *still* doesn't solve the problem, you probably have a DOA ("Dead On Arrival") and should return it to the store for a swap.  (be sure to mention "DOA")

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: No, sorry that doesn´t work. If i use this combination i only get into the normal boot process.

Comment: Answer edited.  If that doesn't solve the problem, return your phone and get another one as per last paragraph...  **:-(**